# Обособленные члены предложения

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Какое предложение осложнено  обособленным членом с пояснительным значением?
1. В субботу, после блинов, едем кататься с гор.
2. Тяжелые грозди сирени дышали, росою горя.
3. По всей ширине Лены торчали в разных направлениях льдины, или, по-местному, торосья.

Answer (score 2):

1.*В субботу,(когда именно?) после блинов, едем кататься с гор.* - уточняющий оборот.

2.*Тяжелые грозди сирени дышали,(как? что делая?) росою горя.* обособленное обстоятельство, выраженное деепричастным оборотом.

3.*По всей ширине Лены торчали в разных направлениях льдины, или (то есть), по-местному, торосья.* - пояснительный оборот, **или** здесь в значении "**то есть**".

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html